# Schedule a Python script in crontab on Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I've scheduled my Python script to be executed once an hour by typing `crontab -e` in the shell, then adding this line of text to the cron file:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/myUserName/automatedProject/test.py &>> /home/myUserName/automatedProject/log.txt
```

but no matter what variations I try, it doesn't execute.

As a test script, I'm using Jessica Yung's [simple script](http://www.jessicayung.com/automate-running-a-script-using-crontab/) to append a timestamp to a file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import time
filename = "record_time.txt"
current_time = time.strftime('%a %H:%M:%S')
with open(filename, 'a') as handle:
    handle.write(str(current_time))
    handle.write('\n')
```

Comment: Cron does not run as `your username`. Therefore do not try to access files files based upon your home directory. The cron logfile varies by Linux distribution: look for cron errors in `/var/log/syslog`. This may also help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/418237/how-to-detect-error-in-cron-jobs

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, I've moved everything into `/opt/*` but the Google Compute Engine VM still doesn't execute my cron job, not even when I set the cron time/date options to `* * * * *` (all 5 options as "any")

Comment: What do the logfiles show you?

Comment: `cron` _does_ run crontab commands under your user ID.  Note that that Python script writes directly into a file named `record_time.txt` in the current directory, which should be your home directory.  Check that file to see if the command is being executed.  The script does not print anything, so the redirect into `log.txt` will not collect anything. (It's always a good idea to run a command manually before you put it into a crontab, just to make sure it behaves the way you expect in normal circumstances.)

Comment: Hi @ottomeister, thanks for that. i realized it was a local path and changed it to an absolute path. the command runs manually, but it doesn't run not when it's put into `crontab`.

Comment: My `cron` does not like the `&>>` redirection, because that's a `bash` syntax and `cron` uses plain old `sh` to run crontab jobs.  Try changing that from `&>> /path/to/logfile` to `>> /path/to/logfile  2>&1` which is the traditional `sh` way of doing the same thing.  If that doesn't fix it then let's start from square one and check that the `cron` service is actually running (do `ps -efa | grep cron`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Google Compute Engine, with an Ubuntu 16.04 VM, the user-level cron jobs don't seem to be kicked off at all; however, root-level jobs work as expected.

Instead of editing crontab like this:

`crontab -e`

use `sudo crontab -e`

A simple, working example is `* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/myUserName/test.py` to run `test.py` once a minute.